# Assigning variable in a block

Tags: ruby, architecture

I think everyone has encountered something like this piece of code:

```
def query(sql)
  logger.debug "Db: Executing query #{sql}"
  result = nil
  ts = Benchmark.realtime do
    result = @db.exec sql
  end
  logger.debug "Db: Query completed in #{ts}"
  result
end
```

Quite frankly, this looks ugly. Is there a more elegant way to achieve the same results?

Comment: Can you provide more elegant code on another languages?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ perhaps?

Comment: That doesn't seem all that irregular. Situations like this should be rare.

Answer (score 2):

You could write your own wrapper method like below and hide the ugliness:

```
require 'benchmark'

def bm (description, &block)
  [].tap do |result|
  ts = Benchmark.realtime do
    result <<  block.call
  end
    p "#{description} completed in #{ts}"
  end.first
end

result =  bm("db query") {"db result"}
p result
```

Output:

```
"db query completed in 5.131e-06"
"db result"
```